# How to make a binary or .deb from application built from source?

Tags: compiling, raspberry-pi, source, opencv

I built OpenCV library from source on Raspberry Pi 3 and I don't want to repeat same, time consuming task on my other Raspberry Pis. Is there any way to generate binary or deb files of the built opencv library so that I can copy them and install using dpkg or apt ?

As you might know, make for opencv takes forever (approx 4 hours using `make -j2`. So having a binary will save lots of time.

Comment: Short answer: There is. Long answer: It is application specific, and unless you take time to write a couple of proper questions, this one is too broad. How about reading the instructions and README files, and Makefiles of said packages before dumping here a vague question?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Ok other applications and dependencies can be built in short amount of time, I was looking specifically for OpenCV library.

Comment: I've used the solution with `checkinstall` I described in my answer to distribute `opencv` and some other libraries over a bunch of embedded devices. Works perfect for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are libraries you can build with the classical

```
./configure
make
make install
```

you can install `checkinstall`:

```
apt-get install checkinstall
```

and simply change the last step to:

```
./configure
make
checkinstall
```

Answer the questions and have your debian package. Please note that `checkinstall` will not free you from caring about dependencies, so if you are lazy, the packages will work on other identical systems, but will also install without warning on systems with missing dependencies. You remain responsible for informing `checkinstall` about that!

Comment: I tried `checkinstall` but got an error
`Installing with make install...

    ========================= Installation results===========================
    Makefile:2484: recipe for targetcmake_check_build_system' failed make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Segmentation fault

    ****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

    Cleaning up...OK`

Comment: And what is in line 2484 of the makefile? I suggest to open another question if you can't solve this with the help of the search engine of your choice. The problem is beyond the focus of this question, I think.